# Laravel Query Builder: MySQL 'LIKE' inside a multiple where conditioned query

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

Im trying to do a query where i have **multiple** conditions (including **%LIKE%** operator) but can't figure how to do it in Laravel's **array** way with query builder.

```
$where = ['category' => $c->id, 'name' => $c->name];
$q = Store::where($where)->get();
```

That way it would return an array of objects with the equal of the name, not the similar matches. Is it possible to do a %LIKE% search in that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should chain them like this:

```
DB::table('your-table-name')
    ->where('category','=','$c->id')
    ->where('name','=','$c->name')
    ->where('email', 'LIKE', '%test%')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Somehow i read in docs it should'nt be this way, but it is, thanks